# Dose density matrix with off-diagonal elements equal to zero has maximum von-Neumann entropy?

Tags: it.information-theory, quantum-mechanics, schur-functions

## von-Neumann entropy

I know von-Neumann entropy on density matrix $S=-{\rm Tr}(\rho \ln\rho)$ is similar to Shannon entropy $S=-\sum_i p_i\ln p_i$ in classical mechanics. And I want to get Bose-Einstein distribution and Fermi-Dirac distribution with the principle of maximum entropy. I work with some key points shown in this document [http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~marekgluza/ASM2_16/sheet06.pdf](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/%7Emarekgluza/ASM2_16/sheet06.pdf).

## Statement of Problem

What I was confused is "Among all density matrices with the same diagonal (in some basis), the matrix with all entries outside the diagonal equal to zeros has the largest von-Neumann entropy". How can we get this conclusion?

## Schur's theorem

The document also says it's a consequence of Schur's theorem. Does Schur's theorem say von-Neumann entropy is concave? And this problem [Bound on the von Neumann entropy of a positive, positive semi-definite, and unit-trace density matrix?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68249/bound-on-the-von-neumann-entropy-of-a-positive-positive-semi-definite-and-unit) also talks about Schur-concave functions. But how can we know density matrix with off-diagonal elements equal to zero has maximum entropy?

Comment: If you fix the energy and maximize the entropy you get the canonical density matrix. If you further fix the particle number (on average) you get the grand canonical. To get Bose Einstein and Fermi Dirac you further need to assume that particles are non-intersecting.

Comment: yeah, thanks for your concise and clear reply. I know the conclusion, but I want to derive the conclusion more strictly and want to know what I can get from the principle of maximum entropy if the particles are interacting?

Comment: One way is to consider dephasing in the energy eigenbasis. Such dephasing doesn't change the energy but the entropy increases. So the maximum has to be sought among states diagonal in the energy eigenbasis and so you are left with the classical case.

Comment: Is dephasing just the off-diagonal element in the density matrix $\rho$ in the energy eigenbasis? But why "dephasing doesn't change the energy but the entropy increases"? Could you show the reason more explicitly and mathematically, or some related articles about the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Dephasing kills the off-diagonal elements. I'll try to post an answer (probably tomorrow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following observation allows to reduce the problem to the classical, commuting case.

I will assume finite dimensionality although generalizations are possible.
Let the Hamiltonian have the following spectral decomposition, $H = \sum_k E_k \Pi_k $, where $E_k, \Pi_k$ are respectively the eigenvalues, spectral projectors.

Define the following dephasing map:

\begin{align}
D_H(X) &:= \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_0^T \!\! dt \, e^{-it H} X e^{itH} \\
 & = \sum_k \Pi_k X \Pi_k . 
\end{align}

Note that the first line is also valid in infinite dimensions. It is easy to see that $D$ is positive, trace preserving and unital (in fact it is completely positive as one has a Kraus representation).

Let the entropy of a state $\rho$ be given by

$$S(\rho) = -\operatorname{Tr} [\rho \ln \rho]. $$

The observation is the following. It turns out that, for any quantum state $\rho$

$$S (D_H (\rho)) \ge S(\rho) . $$

Since we want to maximize the entropy we can do so among the fixed points of $D_H$ which are states that commutes with $H$. From here on you can follow the classical proof with Lagrange multipliers.

The observation is part of the characterization of entropy increasing channels. In particolar, if $T$ is positive, trace preserving and unital, and $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a concave function, then

$$
\operatorname{Tr} [h(T(\rho))] \ge \operatorname{Tr}[h(\rho)]$$
for all density operators $\rho$.

For a proof, see Theorem 8.8 and corollary 8.1 of *Quantum channels & operations guided tour* by M. Wolf ([freely available here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiG5ODx8ef7AhXlzIUKHbxGCK0QFnoECA4QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww-m5.ma.tum.de%2Ffoswiki%2Fpub%2FM5%2FAllgemeines%2FMichaelWolf%2FQChannelLecture.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0ifu39ST08JdtnUx7QZI5s)).

Comment: So the main idea here is to use $T(\rho)=\sum_k\Pi_k\rho\Pi_k$ and $h(x)=-x\ln x$.  Then beacause $T$ is positive, trace preserving and unital and $h$ is concave, so we can use corollary 8.1 in the tour, which means that density matrix mapped by $T$ will has bigger entropy. And the role of $T$ is just to kill off-diagonal elements in density matrix. So in total, density matrix with off-diagonal elements equal to zero has maximum entropy. Do I understand the idea right?

Comment: Absolutely. And obviously dephasing in the energy eigenbasis ($D_H$) doesn't change the value of the (mean) energy.